# Can I use CSS to apply styles based on child element count?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a situation where *n* elements can be present and any can be deleted. But at the point where only one element is present, the deletion should be disabled (ideally by setting `display:none`):

[image: three items with deletion button]

And only one item:

[image: one item and no deletion button]

My question is if I can do something like this:

```
DIV.items:ONLY_ONE_CHILD DIV.item BUTTON.delete {
   display:none;
}
```

No is an acceptable answer but in that case I'd like to know about the *closest possibility* or potentional *future options*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify it on the parent (`DIV.items`), but you can on the child (`DIV.item`) with the `:only-child` pseudo-class. Since you're styling a descendant *of the child* here, what you're looking to do is in fact possible:

```
DIV.item:only-child BUTTON.delete {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory note that `:only-child` is only supported on IE9 and newer and all other browsers. Some day I hope I don't have to state this anymore, but then I'd have to do the same once browsers start implementing level 4 selectors...